# Reading CSV in Recordset?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, recordset

Let me start off by saying that I am very greatful to have a place to go to when I need help with some code and I'm even more thankful when I see people trying to help out, so for everyone here Thank you for looking at my question/problem even if you don't have an answer.

With that said, on with my question/problem:

I have been trying to get this to work but I cannot seem to find the syntax error!! :-(

Can anyone please help me...

Here is the code:

```
dim strPathtoCSVFolder,strPathtoCSVFile,strPathtoCSVFileTWO

strPathtoCSVFolder="D:\classic_asp\test\" & Request.QueryString("XTNO") & "\Data\"
strPathtoCSVFile="Unit_" & Request.QueryString("XTNO") & "_Year_" & Request.QueryString("year") & "_Q_" & Request.QueryString("q") & "_MERGE_DataCsv.csv"
strPathtoCSVFileTWO="Unit_" & Request.QueryString("XTNO") & "_Year_" & Request.QueryString("year") & "_Q_" & Request.QueryString("q") & "_MERGE_DataCsv_SORTED.csv"

Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strPathtoCSVFolder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""
dim strDirInfoX
strDirInfoX="SELECT STATE, SUM(GALLONS) as Total FROM " & strPathtoCSVFile & " GROUP BY STATE "

'''''' response.write strDirInfoX
dim strTxttoMem

dim strsource
strsource="RS.Open " & strDirInfoX & " , Conn, 1, 3, &H0001"
RS.Open strsource
'response.write strsource

redim FieldNames(rs.fields.count)
redim FieldTypes(rs.fields.count)
For i = 0 To (rs.Fields.Count - 1)
    FieldNames(i) = cstr(trim(rs.Fields.Item(i).Name))
    FieldTypes(i) = cstr(trim(rs.Fields.Item(i).Type))
Next
RS.Close

RS.Open strDirInfoX, Conn, 3, 3, &H0001
Do Until RS.EOF
''''    for i=0 to ubound(FieldNames)-1
'''     response.write(FieldNames(i) & " = " & RS.Fields.Item(FieldNames(i)) & "<br>")

strTxttoMem=strTxttoMem & RS("STATE") & RS("total")

''  next
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
RS.Close
Conn.Close

dim fs,tfile
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set tfile=fs.CreateTextFile(strPathtoCSVFolder & strPathtoCSVFileTWO)


tfile.WriteLine(strTxttoMem)
tfile.close
set tfile=nothing
set fs=nothing
```

Thank you so much for any help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, without running your code, I spotted an error in this part:

```
dim strsource 
strsource="RS.Open " & strDirInfoX & " , Conn, 1, 3, &H0001" 
RS.Open strsource
```

or to shorten it, you are doing this:

```
RS.Open "RS.Open " & strDirInfoX & " , Conn, 1, 3, &H0001"
```

change it to `RS.Open strDirInfoX, Conn, 1, 3, &H0001` and that part will run better.

Comment: That was it... I cannot believe it. it took me over 4+ hrs of trying all kinda stuff to make it work and it was a "..Thanks again so much for all of your help

Comment: hmm, it also works with: "RS.Open " & strDirInfoX & ", Conn, 1, 3, &H0001.... Sweet.. so happy that you got it working for me... thanks a million, you just made my day! thats for sure.

Comment: congrats AutomatedChaos.. @compcobalt another advise.. try "set RS = Conn.Execute(strDirInfoX)" if the extra parameters are not necessary, saves you some lines and is more readable

Comment: @compcobalt You're welcome, I'm glad you have it running now.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost impossible to answer, there could be multiple errors and much depends on what is declared before, eg an option explicit makes a huge difference (and is advisable).

Since debugging in the browser is difficult at best, you copy this code - that comes from an asp file i guess - and put it in a vbs script, replace the response.write with wscript.echo and run the code.
Then you get an error at some line, correct it and so on, afterward replace the echos's by response.write's and you'r done.

I also recommend useing Firefox and the Firebug plugin to do your testing, you will get more debugging info there, at least use the developer view in Chrome or IE

Success..

Comment: I will make a note of that, that is for sure.. when I think of it now, if I was looknig at the error line only and not the code around it i would probably slove it much faster or it would of helped you guys in pinpointing the problem. Thanks again Peter

Answer (score 0):

Been some time working on VBScript but shouldnt tfile.close be tfile.Close?

Comment: vbscript is not case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reading the file as a text file rather than connecting to it with an ADODB connection? Since it is a CSV file, you might be able to read it as a plain text file. You can split the content with comma and loop and get what you want.

If you want to access it using ADODB connection, try saving the file with an xlsx extention(Either copy the contents through code or save it manually. The same code might work).

Shamelessly adding a link to my blog on ADO

http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=3033014869583885023#editor/target=post;postID=8274119342550879092

Comment: sweet, I will have a look into this also. Thanks! :)